# How to implement "debouncing" for event-driven microservices?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, apache-kafka, azure-functions, microservices

I have 2 microservices running in a Kubernetes cluster on Azure. The "Project"-microservice sends out an event to Kafka when a project has been updated. The "Analytics"-microservice consumes the event, does some expensive calculations, and finally sends out an e-mail containing the results.

To avoid spamming the receiver, I want to implement some kind of debouncing pattern so that calculations are only done when an hour has passed since receiving the last update-event. Since the "Analytics"-microservice would be idle for most of the time and cold starts are not a problem, it would be advantageous if resources are unreserved while it is inactive.

How would one implement a debouncing scenario when using Kafka? I have thought of introducing a less resource-intensive microservice with the sole purpose of triggering the "Analytics"-microservice once an internal clock has expired. Is this a sensible solution? I would appreciate the input of someone who has dealt with a similar problem before.

Comment: Why would you handle them only once an hour, and how is that event driven? And if it's an requirement, why not just implement a GET endpoint and poll that once an hour?

Comment: A user updates a project via a REST endpoint. The "Project"-microservice sends a "ProjectUpdated"-event to a Kafka topic. The "Analytics"-microservice listens to it. It's event-driven in the sense that producers and consumers don't know each other.

Since the events are initiated by user behavior, they usually come in short intervals. I want to avoid executing an expensive analytics calculation and sending out an e-mail for every event. It is sufficient if this is done once in a time frame.

A periodically called GET endpoint will find projects in an intermediary state.

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider Temporal’s *durable timers*. See here: https://docs.temporal.io/docs/workflows/

You can also consider combining Temporal with [Spiderwiz](https://spiderwiz.org/project/) to streamline your entire workflow.